# typeorm) compile error on deleting many-to-one variable

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Here is my entities, delete-opration-related code and error logs.
I'm using typeorm with nestjs.

- User

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(['username'])
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column()
    username: string;
    @Column()
    password: string;
    @OneToMany((type) => Board, (board) => board.user, { eager: true, cascade: ['remove'] })
    boards: Board[];
}
```

- Board

```js
@Entity()
export class Board extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column()
    title: string;
    @Column()
    description: string;
    @Column()
    status: BoardStatus;
    @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.boards, { eager: false })
    user: User;
}
```

- Delete operation code **(Error occurs here)**

  - repository is the basic repository of typeorm.

```js
@Injectable()
export class BoardsService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Board)
        private readonly repository: Repository<Board>
    ) { }

   // bla-bla...

    async deleteBoardById(id: number, user: User): Promise<void> {
        // below { id, user } complains the error.
        const result = await this.repository.delete({ id, user });

        if (result.affected === 0) {
            throw new NotFoundException(`Can't find Board with id ${id}`);
        }
    }

   // bla-bla...
}
```

- error logs

```
 Argument of type '{ id: number; user: User; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | FindOptionsWhere<Board> | Date | ObjectID | string[] | number[] | Date[] | ObjectID[]'.
  Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
    Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOperator<any> | FindOptionsWhere<User> | FindOptionsWhere<User>[] | EqualOperator<User> | undefined'.
      Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<User>'.
        Types of property 'boards' are incompatible.
          Type 'Board[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | FindOptionsWhere<Board> | FindOperator<any> | FindOptionsWhere<Board>[] | EqualOperator<Board> | undefined'.
            Type 'Board[]' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Board>[]'.
              Type 'Board' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Board>'.
                Types of property 'hasId' are incompatible.
                  Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

56         const result = await this.repository.delete({ id, user });
```

I spent so many times in googles, typeorm documents and so on, but I can't find solution

Is there any solution about it?

---

Self answer:
removing "extends BaseEntity" from each entities, the compile error gone. May be FUNCTION variables inside BaseEntity is not assignable to FindOptionWhere.

Comment: Is it not `{ where: { id, user } }`?

Comment: @kellys not working, same error result.

Comment: maybe delete them separately: `boardRepository.delete(id)` and `userRepository.delete(user.ud)`. You can also use a query runner to execute it in one transaction.

Comment: @marcel Thanks to reply. but that is not what I want. I want to delete Board which matches both id and user. i.e) the Board will be deleted which owned by current user.

Comment: I finally found then solution. removing "extends BaseEntity" from each entities, the compile error gone. May be FUNCTION variables inside BaseEntity is not assignable to FindOptionWhere<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using QueryBuilder.

```
async deleteBoardById(id: number, user: User): Promise<void> {
const result = await this.boardRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .delete()
  .from(Board)
  .where({
    id,
    user,
  })
  .execute();

if (result.affected === 0) {
  throw new NotFoundException(
    `Can't find board with id ${id} with userId ${user.id}`,
  );
}
```